# How can we display product price $104 on the cart while the credit card payment method is checked?

Tags: plugin-development, customization, woocommerce-offtopic

I am not familiar with Wordpress functionality, I hope you guys can help on the  issue below:

We are having an issue while displaying the price under checkout.

1. We have two payment methods:

   a) Check

   b) Credit Card
2. If customer pays by Credit card it includes 4% credit card charges (for that we are using Woocommerce payment gateway based pricing).
3. Since we do not want to display extra credit card amount, we did hide the row using display:none;
4. But the price displays. For example: $100 on cart and total it shows $104 so the customer gets confused on the price, but we do not want to display the credit card charges separately.

How can we display product price $104 on the cart while the credit card payment method is checked?

[image]

Comment: I guess this is WooCommerce? So you only want the 4% charge to appear at check out if / when they select card not check? I think this is probably a question for whoever wrote the plugin you're using that adds the card charges.

Comment: Thanks @Rup for replying, Yes it is woocommerce and we required 4% charge for only card.